# Pandas column based on previous row multicolumn criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this has been asked a few times, but I cannot get to solve it. I'm terribly sorry.
I have a dataframe 'stock_df' with 1 column with 'RSI_14' values. I'm a newbie, so in order to make it easier I initialize 3 columns with == 0 for 3 states. This auxiliary columns are to explain better the question:

- More than 70 --> 'plus70' = 1
- Less than 30 --> 'minus30' = 1
- Between 70 and 30 --> 'between' = 1

The objective is to make a **'Signal'** that is **+1** when 'RSI_14' > 70 and **-1** when 'RSI_14' < 30 (that's easy), but the tricky part is that when the state is 'between' 70 and 30 I need to put the former **+1 or -1** state in **'Signal'**, and **keep that number until the next +1 or -1** change of state and keep with that on and on...
This shouldn't be that difficult with .shift(1) or .diff(1), but I don't get it.

This is the desired outcome:
[Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqxJd.png)

I've tried **np.where,** but it's the last "stock_df['Signal'].shift(1)" that doesn't seem to work:

```
stock_df['Signal'] = np.where(stock_df['RSI_14'] > 70, 1, (np.where(stock_df['RSI_14'] < 30, -1, stock_df['Signal'].shift(1))))
```

I think the solution must be in **"groupby"** with **"transform"** but I've tried many different ways, but I'm quite clumsy...
I really think is with groupby. I've checked A LOT of answers here, but I don't get to solve it.
I'd really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please see [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input and expected output in the text of your question, not as an image or link. This will help us to help you, as we can't copy and paste an image to help you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create any additional columns to achieve this. Just use:

```
condition_values = stock_df.RSI_14.values
signal = []
last = None
for item in condition_values:
    if item < 30:
        signal.append(-1)
        last = -1
    elif item > 70:
        signal.append(1)
        last = 1
    else:
        signal.append(last)

 df['signal'] = signal
```

Change the none in the beginning to your liking value.

Comment: Thank you very much Olca! This is it! 
I hadn't thought this way. 
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet could work. Assigning signal value to be equal to the previous row signal value (when between equals 1) should get the job done.

```
for i in range(len(stock_df)):
    if stock_df['between'][i] == 1:
        if i == 0:
            stock_df['Signal'][i] = 1
        else:
            stock_df['Signal'][i] = stock_df['Signal'][i - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks Nur! I'll go with Olca's code but yours works too! Thanks!!